# discord.net The server responded with error 50001: Missing Access

Tags: c#, discord.net

I would like to retrieve users in discord guild but I get an error with cryptic message.

```
The server responded with error 50001: Missing Access
```

The bot has `Administrator` permission, that's what it states in `Server settings > Roles > Permissions`

Perhaps something else is needed to tick off in configuration.

Your thoughts?

Thanks for help.

**Code**

```cs
  class Program
    {
        private static IDiscordClient _client;
        private static bool _isRunning = false;
        private static Timer _timer;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(ProcessExit);
            var client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig()
            {
                AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
                MessageCacheSize = 200,
            });
            var botToken = "...";

            await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, botToken);
            await client.StartAsync();
            client.Ready += Ready;
            _client = client;
            await Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        }

        private static async Task Ready()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(GetUsers, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }

        private static async void GetUsers(object state)
        {
            if (_isRunning)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isRunning = true;

            try
            {
                var guilds = await _client.GetGuildsAsync();
                var guild = guilds.First();

                var users = await guild.GetUsersAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(users.Count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            _isRunning = false;

        }

        static void ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (_client as DiscordSocketClient).LogoutAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
```

**Discord Developer Portal - Scopes and bot permissions under OAuth2 configuration**

[image]

**Link which I used to invite bot to server.**

```
https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<>&permissions=8&scope=applications.commands%20bot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently server member intent must be toggled to see guild members.

[image: developer portal bot]

Answer (score 3):

Glad OP has already solved their issue; I came from a search and solved it by making sure my bot invite link has `&scope=bot%20applications.commands` at the end, as well as the "Use slash commands" permission (or have your bot be admin).

The Bot's invite link is in the OAuth > URL Generator in the Discord Developer Portal -- `https://discord.com/developers/applications/<your_app_id>/oauth2/url-generator`

Also, make sure the REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT option in the Bot menu is off, otherwise you'll get a "Bot requires a code grant" response from the OAuth invite.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the server role order was wrong. The bot was able to assign any roles that was below the bot's role on the role list, but nothing that was above.

I went to "Server Settings" -> "Roles" -> and moved up the bots role to the top, Clicked save and it was working after that.

It can be tested by clicking on "More" -> "View server as role" and then try to assign the role you want.